# How to include transitions with inline javascript 'style' changes?

Tags: javascript, css-transitions

My code shows and hides divs depending on which button the user clicks, implemented by simple `myElement.style.display = 'none';` statements.

Can transitions be used when these divs are shown/hidden? I.e. when button-1 is clicked, text relating to button-1 fades **into** view; when button-2 is clicked, text relating to button-2 fades into view as the previous button-1 text **fades out**?

As is, the divs snap in and out of view. I am looking for a smoother transition.

I have attempted it with the code which is shown commented out. It just doesn't work. Any tips are much appreciated, thank you.

**JS**

```
 var visibleDivId = null;

function divVisibility(divId) {
  if(visibleDivId === divId) {
    visibleDivId = null;
  } else {
    visibleDivId = divId;
  }
  hideNonVisibleDivs();
}

function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
  var i, divId, div;
  for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divId = divs[i];
    respoding_div = document.getElementById(divId);
    if(visibleDivId == divId) {
      respoding_div.style.display = 'block';
      // respoding_div.style.transition = 'display 0.3s ease-in block'
    }
    else {
      respoding_div.style.display = 'none';
      // respoding_div.style.transition = 'display 0.3s ease-in none'
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

<body>

<div class="container" style="text-align:center; margin:0 auto;">


    <div class="card-container" style="margin:0 auto; width:50%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; padding-bottom:10px;">

        <div class='accordion' onclick="divVisibility('Core1');">
            <img src='https://img.icons8.com/dotty/2x/external-link-squared.png' width="50px">Button-1
        </div>

        <div class='accordion' onclick="divVisibility('Core2');">
            <img src='https://img.icons8.com/dotty/2x/globe-earth.png' width="50px">Button-2
        </div>

        <div class='accordion' onclick="divVisibility('Core3');">
            <img src='https://img.icons8.com/dotty/2x/torrent.png' width="50px">Button-3
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="all_divs">
        <div id="Core1" class="subdiv" style="display:none;">TEXT #1</div>
        <div id="Core2" class="subdiv" style="display:none;">TEXT #2</div>
        <div id="Core3" class="subdiv" style="display:none;">TEXT #3</div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  font-family: "IBM Plex Sans", sans-serif;
    }

.accordion {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left:100px;
    padding-right:100px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 80px;
}

.accordion:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.accordion img {
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.all_divs > div {
    color: #232f3e;
    width: 95%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#fafafa;
    position: absolute;
    padding:2%;
    border-top: 2px solid #e6e7e8;
}

h1{
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: #232f3e;
}

td{
    padding: 2%;
}
```

Comment: `display` is [not an animatable property](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_class_display.asp). You'll need to do something more convoluted than simple show/hide via `display`.

Comment: @Utkanos any tips on what something more convoluted would entail?

Answer (score 0):

it will not work not because of the syntax or something wrong in JS but because of the `display` property can't be transitioned from state to another. u can use `opacity` for that.